# MySQL Workbench test connection using known good online open database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-connection

I am trying to access a MySQL database but workbench times out and I get a 10060 error.

This makes no sense as I have put % against the username so that the database can be accessible from anywhere.

In fact I was able to access it from the same location from my desktop PC, (until my SSD died last week!)

I can access it from my work PC too. I am using a new hp laptop and workbench 6.3 64 bit. Am I missing something? Do I need to install ODBC or something? Is there a known issue with 64 bit?

The handiest thing is to just use a known good MySQL connection and I will know if it is my database or something else. I remember something used to exist for this purpose but I have been googling for about an hour and got nowhere.

Does such a db still exist?

**EDIT**  The loss of connection was caused by an MTU issue on our broadband.

Comment: Another troubleshooting step is trying to access from terminal/command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit more involved than I would have liked but it works.

Create an account on https://www.db4free.net/

Assume when creating the account you use username and password dingbat.

Next lookup the IP address of b4free.net/

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup db4free.net
>
> Server:  bthub.home
>
> Address:  192.XXX.X.XXX
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> Name:    db4free.net
>
> Address:  85.10.205.173

Enter details as a shown below in MySQL workbench

[image]

You can now simply find out if the problem, is on your database or on your firewall, code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such open server and it wouldn't help you anyway, if your problem is e.g. the local firewall. [Watch this troubleshooting video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY) which explains what you can do if a connection fails. If you can access the server from another machine then it is likely that the one that makes problems blocks the connection (usually because of the firewall).